# Implementing a Google Visualization Data Source with the Play Framework

Tags: json, playframework, google-visualization

I'm currently working on a Play! project that involves graphing JSON data similar to the following using the Google Visualization API:

```
[{"votes":4,"ID":123,"rating":50,"name":"Bob"}]
```

My current setup involves using jQuery `$.getJSON` in the view requesting a URL that returns data with `renderJSON()`. I then build the Google Visualization data table with `.each`. This method works fine; however, my future data set could expand such that constructing the data table in this way would seem inefficient.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass the formatted JSON into the [DataTable constructor](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable_literal_constructor_example) or use `google.visualization.Query` and skip the manual addition of the rows, but I'm stuck on how best to accomplish this. Looking at the options, it seems I can either try to format my JSON response similar to the example described in the documentation:

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(
 {
   cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
            {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],
   rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]},
          {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]},
          ...
```

or I could attempt to work with the [Visualization Data Source Library](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_intro.html). Unfortunately, my Java knowledge is not evolved enough for me to determine how to start setting up either within Play! If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm loving the Play! Framework. I never thought I would be able to accomplish so much with so little effort.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not fluent in Java, don't go in the custom datasource direction because apparently, as often, Google provides a nice library but the code is stuck on Java servlets. Unfortunately, Play doesn't use java servlets (which is one reason of being of the framework) and to use Google libraries, you generally have to dig into the code to find the right classes to use.

So I would advise you to use a simple JSON generator creating in Ajax the {cols: ..., rows: ... } on Play side and persist your data using a simple persistence module such as Siena (ok I'm not objective I'm lead dev of siena :)) or JPA if you really want to stay near Java EE world.

You have to write a few code for generating your JSON (GSON is well doc) but it's quite trivial with a few work.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice. I was having a hard time trying to find the right classes to use for the custom data source, so I thought I should make sure I wasn't missing anything too obvious :) I'll see what I can do with GSON. The good news is that my responses will all be relatively consistent as the actual data structure is quite simple. Thanks again!